# Is there any name space called "sdds" ? Because I am not able to find out about it anywhere

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces

I am trying sdds namespace in my code as it is asked to do so but that is throwing me error message.

The code is right below:

```
using namespace sdds;
```

Error message which I am getting is pasted down,

```
Error (active)  E0725   name must be a namespace name   w1p1    D:\w1p1\vendingmaching.cpp  5
```

Comment: No namespaces exist until they are defined.  I suspect that you are expected to include one or more headers that define this `namespace sdds`.

Comment: Why are you even trying to use `using namespace sdds;`?

Comment: "as it is asked to do" what asked you to do this? Did it tell you to include specific files first?

Comment: Yes I have been asked to make sdds namespace and surround the code with it!!!....although I didnt understand it and how to do so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no namespace called `sdds` in the c++ standard library. For the using directive:

```
using namespace sdds;
```

The namespace `sdds` must exist. Note that anybody can create a namespace and name it as they want. If you merely want to silence the error without changing the existing code you can add:

```
 namespace sdds {
 }
```

However, i rather suppose that whoever asked you to *"do so"* expects you to include some header where the namespace called `sdds` is introduced or that you introduce the namespace in your code.